# iOS - bad fence setup - we're setting up a potentially deferrable transaction while we are already tracking an animation fence

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

So could somebody enlighten me on what this error means:

> Mar  8 13:36:36 Black-Taco SpringBoard[54] :  * bad fence setup * we're setting up a potentially deferrable transaction while we are already tracking an animation fence - this will probably cause us to blow the fence

I get this message from the Device Console in Xcode, when I'm trying to rotate my device sometimes it prints out.  I do have some `CALayers` that are animating while i'm trying to rotate but I'm not sure if this is actually a bad error or something i can ignore.

Couldn't find much on the web about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has now gone away in my code.  I was running animations "open-loop" and it seems that somehow perhaps there were too many queued up or something.  I switched to running on a 10hz timer and this message has gone away.  I don't know if i solved or hid the problem or really what the issue was.

Maybe this will help somebody.